# SQL Select a record from multiple dates

Tags: sql

I would like to build a query that returns entries that have been entered in multiple dates.

For example:

```
 Name  |  Country  |  Date
 Name1 | Country1  | Date1
 Name2 | Country2  | Date2
 Name1 | Country2  | Date3
```

I want to be able to select the entries that are entered on at least two separate dates. In this case, my query would return only Name1.

`SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Table`

is all I have so far. This is a simplified example, in my case I actually have multiple joins but what I am looking to figure out how to do is check for a date count with different date values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a group by then a count in the having clause.

```
select Name
from Table
group by Name
having count(*) > 1
```

If you want to not count the same date twice, then you can use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT Date) > 1
```

Comment: +1 but I think you might get false positives for items that have the same date multiple times, so a distinct qualifier would probably be appropriate. Try `count(distinct date)` in the having clause.

Comment: @bluefeet I wasn't worried about that since it wasn't in the requirements, but a DISTINCT Date in the count should work.

Comment: Actually the distinct part was in the req.: _on at least two separate dates_

Comment: @jpw Maybe thats just me misreading the question.  I went off the example data and assumed the dates wouldn't be repeated and likely included time values.

Comment: I absolutely did need two separate dates so the edit was necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In many dialcect of SQL, the fastest way to do this query would be:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.date <> t.date);
```

For best performance, you want an index in `table(name, date)`.

Note the `group by` method is quite reasonable.  I just offer this if performance is an issue.